# It's posible load and unload components in an angular application depends of the resolution?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, load, components

This is my idea.
I have a website with multiple angular components. for example a search box and two custom date-pickers.

I want to have the ability to only load the search box in mobile and a reduced version of the date-picker but in desktop load the full js.

the same for the css, I don't want to load all css rules and use media queries. I want load mobile css and in desktop load the a plus pack of other new css.